# count iteration of recurring statuses

Tags: sql, oracle

Updated:

I have table that logs statuses of an approval workflow. The table looks like this:

```
NUMBER      STATUS          STATUS_DATE             

248033      Registration    2017-12-02 12:20:58.0       
248033      Processed       2017-12-04 11:29:16.0   
248033      Approve         2017-12-04 11:32:11.0   
248033      Approved        2017-12-04 16:27:45.0   
248033      Completed       2017-12-05 06:01:29.0   
248033      Registration    2017-12-07 10:02:16.0   
248033      Approve         2017-12-08 15:48:09.0   
248033      Processed       2017-12-08 16:15:00.0   
248033      Completed       2017-12-09 10:23:32.0   
248033      Registration    2018-07-20 16:49:25.0   
248033      Processed       2018-07-20 16:54:32.0   
248033      Completed       2018-07-25 11:41:59.0   
248033      Registration    2019-03-11 09:56:10.0   
248033      Processed       2019-03-11 09:56:11.0   
248033      Completed       2019-03-12 06:01:10.0
```

I want to count the number of times (iterations / cycles) that a document has been approved. A iteration always starts with 'REGISTRATION' and ends with 'COMPLETED'. But in between these two statuses it is possible to see a lot of 'flipping' back and forth between statuses. Also 'Processed', or 'Approve' , or 'Approved' can be omitted.

I want to group the approval iterations like below:

```
NUMBER      STATUS          STATUS_DATE             ITERATION

248033      Registration    2017-12-02 12:20:58.0       1   
248033      Processed       2017-12-04 11:29:16.0       1
248033      Approve         2017-12-04 11:32:11.0       1
248033      Approved        2017-12-04 16:27:45.0       1
248033      Completed       2017-12-05 06:01:29.0       1
248033      Registration    2017-12-07 10:02:16.0       2
248033      Approve         2017-12-08 15:48:09.0       2
248033      Processed       2017-12-08 16:15:00.0       2
248033      Completed       2017-12-09 10:23:32.0       2
248033      Registration    2018-07-20 16:49:25.0       3
248033      Processed       2018-07-20 16:54:32.0       3
248033      Completed       2018-07-25 11:41:59.0       3
248033      Registration    2019-03-11 09:56:10.0       4
248033      Processed       2019-03-11 09:56:11.0       4
248033      Completed       2019-03-12 06:01:10.0       4
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this using Oracle SQL?

Comment: Please explain the logic.  It is not obvious.

Comment: ITERATION values exist in example you posted, while message text says that it does not. That's a contradiction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on a few observations please: Iteration 2 has no Processed or completed. Iteration 3 does not have a "Registration", and Registration 4 has 2 registrations, 2 processed and 2 completed records?

Comment: Can't really get the logic of it... maybe I'm going dumb today... I'll get a coffee and will read it again.

Comment: The table is an audit trail of an approval workflow. The original table has only the columns Number, Status and Status_Date. The column ITERATION is what I want to add myself. The table logs statuses that a certain document goes through when it is processed. A document can get into 'registration' status multiple times. Same is true for the other statuses. When a document has reached status 'Processed', the cycle is completed. This is usually the end stage of the approval flow.

Comment: I will update the post to clarify better.

Comment: finished updating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count registrations with an `OVER` clause:

```
select
  number,
  status,
  status_date,
  count(case when status = 'Registration' then 1 end) over (order by status_date)
    as iteration
from mytable
order by status_date;
```

EDIT: You say that 'Registration' can occur multiple times before a 'Completed'. You can count 'Completed' instead and only add 1 if the row itself is not a 'Completed' row.

```
select
  number,
  status,
  status_date,
  count(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 end) over (order by status_date) +
    case when status = 'Completed' then 0 else 1 end as iteration
from mytable
order by status_date;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I am looking for. What I failed to mention is that a document can cycle through statuses Registration - Processed - Registration - Processed etc. The cycle is completed when 'Completed' is reached. A new cycle starts with 'Registration' again.

Comment: Certainly pointed me in the right direction! I will add a sub-select with the LAG function. Will post my results tomorrow.

Comment: No big deal. Count 'Completed'  instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten This is a very clever solution and it seems to work.